# RecyclerView itemView onClickListener when there is a textView with link

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Well I have a `RecyclerView` that user can select rows. I've added `onClickListener` to `itemView` to change background of selected row.

```
private void bindSelect(final Comment comment){

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(comment.isScelected()){
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                comment.setScelected(false);
            }else{
                itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.comment_select_background));
                comment.setScelected(true);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Everthing works untill we deciced to enable `autolink` in text view in rows.

After that when user click on textview containing `link`, itemView.onClickListner does not catch click!!

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:wisgoon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/comment_avatar"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/regular_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/regular_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eight" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comment_avatar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment_avatar"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorDark"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/four"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/four"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comment_name"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment_name"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
    android:textSize="11sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/comment_name"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/four"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/eight"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/minus_four"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comment_avatar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment_avatar"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorDarkGray"
    android:textSize="11sp" />
```

How To solve this issue?

**Update**
Dudes I've multiple Clickable Area in a row

Comment: What is your question? You want to redirect to link or proceed to your click action?

Comment: @mani he is saying that he wants to proceed to the click action.

Comment: @Mani I want to catch click listener

Comment: @MAY3AM see my answer.

Comment: @MAY3AM add android:clickable="false" to all children of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an `OnTouchListener` to the `TextView` with the link enable and return a `false` boolean to show the touch has not been handled

Much Like this

```
findViewById("R.id.comment_text").setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            // Do what you want with text link
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml` file, You've set autolink for all. As per your comment, you want to show the link, but need to disable the click event. so add below line in your `xml` file.

```
android:linksClickable:"false"
```

Comment: But I don't want to disable the links, You know what, Assume there is a multi line text, and inside of that is a link, well I want user to be able to open link when click directly on link, and meanwhile be able to select row if click on any other side of textview

Comment: @MAY3AM Then what's the problem.? It should work as per your xml file.

Comment: No it does not work, when text contain links, if user click on textview ( any where except link, if click on link, links fired properly ), `itemView` does not catch the click and then row background and comment select status does not changed, the problem is this :(